# ASP.NET C# How to hide/show text when you click a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

Id like to show label(make visible a hidden) and change the text of a Button when clicked, and be able to click the button again to show its original text and hide the label .`

```
    public partial class TestClick : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
        {

            btnShowButtonText.Text = "Button";
            lblShowText.Visible = false;

        }
    }
    protected void btnShowButtonText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            btnShowButtonText.Text = "Hide gift voucher details";
            lblShowText.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And the problem is? What have you tried?

Comment: Coming back to this, I think it's very bad to do this server-side. This should be client-side functionality.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one count variable.
like this:

```
static  int cnt=0;
    protected void btnShowButtonText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    cnt++;
            if (cnt%2!=0)
            {
                btnShowButtonText.Text = "Hide gift voucher details";
                lblShowText.Visible = true;
            }
    if (cnt%2==0) 
            {

                btnShowButtonText.Text = "Button";
                lblShowText.Visible = false;

            }
        }
```

when you clicks first time , button text is "Hide gift voucher details"
next time button text is "Button"

Comment: The count variable has to be static. Otherwise the value gets lost, because of ASP.NET and the roundtrip between client and server.

Comment: Besides the solution probably working, this is client-side functionality. Watch how your server responds to a few hundred simultaneous people trying to hide/show a label or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hiddenfield to determine the status of the button and the text:

```
  public partial class TestClick : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
    {

        btnShowButtonText.Text = "Button";
        lblShowText.Visible = false;
    }
   }

protected void btnShowButtonText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(hiddenField.Value == "0")
    {
       btnShowButtonText.Text = "Hide gift voucher details";
       lblShowText.Visible = true;
       hiddenField.Value = "1";
    }
    else
    {
       btnShowButtonText.Text = "Button";
       lblShowText.Visible = false;
       hiddenField.Value = "0";
    }
}
```